# Thunderbird 14 acount overview says "Inbox (100)"

Tags: windows-7, email, thunderbird

The new overview of Thunderbird 14 says: 
Posteingang (100) / Inbox (100)

The number should be the actual number of emails in the inbox.
But I have actually 205 emails in y inbox.
So why does it say all the time on the overview, that there are only 100 emails in my inbox?

I mean the overview where you can see the used space, when you sent the emails (graphs) and the most emails contacts in the last few days)

It seems it is a problem with https://bitbucket.org/squib/mail-summaries/wiki/Home (2.0)

Anyone got some experience with it?

Comment: What makes you think this number is for the total number of mails in a mailbox? While I must admit I am not absolutely sure about where you read this, the numbers in braces after the name in the folder pane show the count of *unread* mails in the corresponding mailboxes.

Comment: seems it is a problem with 2.0 of https://bitbucket.org/squib/mail-summaries/wiki/Home